# Remove button on list item/array in Angular 12

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to remove a list item with the click button, tried various options but it seems to not work. Hope you can help me out with this.

On click i want to remove a list item from my users array. I will link the Typescript code alongside with the HTML.

```js
//Typescript code
import { UsersService } from './../users.service';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Iuser } from '../interfaces/iuser';

@Component({
  selector: 'tr[app-table-row]',
  templateUrl: './table-row.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-row.component.css']
})
export class TableRowComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() item!: Iuser;
  @Output() userDeleted = new EventEmitter();
  

removeUser(item: any) {
    this.userDeleted.emit(item);
  }

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

```html
<th scope="row">{{item.id}}</th>
<td>{{item.name}}</td>
<td>{{item.lastname}}</td>
<td>{{item.city}}</td>
<td> <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="removeUser(item)">remove</button></td>
```

Comment: Hi, userDeleted is a emitter and not the array that you're trying to change the value.

You should **emit()** that the button was clicked and the item that was clicked, and let the **father component** (who has the whole array) to remove the clicked item.

Comment: It might be a consideration to encapsulate all data inside `<tr>` tags and loop through the data, rather than using `scope='row'`

Answer (score 0):

As @Priscila answered, when the button is clicked, you should only emit the action and let the parent component control the respective method i.e. delete or add.

Because that way, it will be easy for the data to be manipulated and handle the component's lifecycle.

Never keep the dead ends running on the app.

Happy Coding :)